# PHP cURL Response query string

Tags: php, http, curl, http-headers

I am making a cURL request in PHP to a URL that immediately redirects back to the original page, appending a query string parameter on to the end of the redirect URL.

For example:
On page load of `https://url0.com`, make a web request to `https://url1.com`

When the request hits `https://url1.com`, it redirects back to `https://url0.com?test=1`

My goal is to get the response headers from the cURL request and just read the query string parameter. The problem is that the response headers always look like this:

`HTTP/1.1 302 Found Cache-Control: private Content-Length: 153 Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8 Location: https://url0.com Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.5 Set-Cookie: ASP.NET_SessionId=0wjspsdi38dnclufiv3znpc; path=/; HttpOnly X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319 X-Powered-By: ASP.NET Date: Tue, 22 Oct 2019 18:44:12 GMT`

I can't figure out how to get the query string from that. I'm using these options:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
```

I don't want the body of the response so I'm using `CURLOPT_NOBODY` to just get the headers.

Thanks!

Comment: You basically have to follow the locations manually until a location is no longer provided. You can do this in a loop, to register all locations.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the manual there's `CURLINFO_EFFECTIVE_URL` for the `curl_getinfo()` function. Something like the following might work:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_exec($ch);
$lastUrl = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_EFFECTIVE_URL); //$lastUrl should contain the last URL called
curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: Unfortunately it looks like it's still returning `https://url0.com` without the query string when I do it this way.